# Android google maps v2 can't align content on custom clusters icons

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing

I'm having trouble aligning cluster content. My problem

[image]

I already tried to make a layout with `textfield` with `id="text"`, but then for some reason the cluster size isn't shown on cluster.

```
final Drawable m1 = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m1);
final Drawable m2 = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m2);
final Drawable m3 = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m3);
final Drawable m4 = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m4);
final Drawable m5 = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m5);
// clusterIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

mClusterIconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
/*//modify padding for one or two digit numbers
if (cluster.getSize() < 10) {
    //mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(40, 20, 0, 0);
    mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(m1.getIntrinsicHeight()/2-15, m1.getIntrinsicWidth()/2-20, 0, 0);
    mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(m1);
}
else {*/
    //final boolean padding = m5.getPadding(1);
    //mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding();
    //mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(m5.getIntrinsicHeight()/2-15, m5.getIntrinsicWidth()/2-20, 0, 0);
    //mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(80, 80, 0, 0);
    //LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //View activityView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cluster_view, null, false);
    mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(m5);
    //mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(activityView);
// }

Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));

markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
```

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For now I'm sticking with defoult cluster icons.